# iOS app binary rejected - IPv6

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession, ipv6

I submitted an app to the store which was subsequently rejected, as it connects to an external server to load a json feed, which runs on IPv4. There are two separate internet connections where I work. The app successfully loads the json feed on one of the connections, but returns a 404 not found error on the other. Obviously when the app was in review it must have returned a 404 error. I am using a NSURLSession to connect to the api, as I understand it this is able to handle IPv4 to IPv6 mapping. What other method can I use to prevent this 404 not found error? The following is a snippet of my code:

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSLog(@"%@", session.configuration);

[[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:jSONURLString]
        completionHandler:^(NSData *rawData,
                            NSURLResponse *response,
                            NSError *error) {
            if ((rawData != nil) && (error == nil)) {
                //NSLog(@"Data: %@", rawData);
                //NSLog(@"%@",response);
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self performSelector:@selector(returnRawData:) withObject:rawData];
                });

            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"error...");
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self performSelector:@selector(noFeedReturned)];
                });
            }
            // handle response

        }] resume];
```

Comment: What's the value of `jSONURLString`?

Comment: Have you verified that the server itself works with IPv6?

Comment: @Feldur: Whether the server uses IPv6 is irrelevant

Comment: It's relevant in that you need a server supporting IPv6 if you intend to test that functionality

Comment: i have same issue how to fix that my app rejected @user102008

Comment: @Feldur: No you don't. IPv4 server is fine.

Comment: @jace: You need to figure out what is wrong with your app

Comment: The server uses IPv4 as far as I know. Isn't NSURLSession supposed to synthesize an IPv6 address automatically?

Comment: Did you test your app on the NAT64 internet sharing network created on a Mac?

Comment: @user102008 Yes, unfortunately the app still fails to retrieve the contents of the json feed.

Comment: @bigdaddyrooster2: It fails to retrieve when on your local NAT64 network? Or it fails to retrieve when Apple reviews it? If it fails to work on your local NAT64 network, you need to debug and make it work before submitting it.

Comment: @bigdaddyrooster2: Is this URL on the public Internet? Or on some local network?

Comment: @user102008 It is a url on the public internet, yes. It fails to retrieve on both the local NAT64 network and when Apple reviews it. The previous version of the app I think got through review because it was submitted before the 1st of June.

Comment: @bigdaddyrooster2: 404 is an error returned by the server, which means it was able to connect to your IPv4 server fine, but your server wasn't happy with the request. So you need to figure out why your server was picky about it.

Comment: @user102008 So the server has been reconfigured and it now returns the json feed no matter what network I have used. I set up the Mac's shared NAT64 IPv6 network to test it, as instructed by Apple, and it works fine. I resubmitted the app and it has yet again been rejected as they say they cannot load any content. I'm unable to reproduce thier problem as it works on the NAT64 network.

Comment: @bigdaddyrooster2 did you solve the issue? I ahem the same issue! I have just resubmitted the app, but they will tell me that it does not load any content ...

Comment: @user3079872 I resubmitted the app a few days later and it was approved. I don't know why because I hadn't made any changes, so maybe the app review team changed the configuration of their setup. Or maybe it depends on who is reviewing it. What exactly was the problem you had? Was it the same setup as the one recommended by Apple (i.e. using the NAT64 translation on the Mac)?

Comment: @bigdaddyrooster2 The problem I had was that the first screen took a long time to come back from getting data from a server that IS NOT IPV6 ready. But it is not my server, so not sure what will happen. I have resubmitted with a small change: to come back quicker if there is no data being obtained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to reconfigure the server to be compatible with both IPv4 and IPv6